# Gradient of refractive index at very short distances

Tags: optics

I have only taken standard (basic) level math courses in high school and had learned only the fundamentals of wave and ray optics in physics classes. Therefore, Im asking only for a very general answer: Is it possible that lens consisting of a flat plate with a very high refractive index gradient (maximal n=2.7, minimal n=1) going across the plane of the lens, with thickness equal to 20 wavelengths be used to refract a laser beam, or is the scale too small for the behaviour of the light to be predicted from the law of refraction?